# How to fix white file explore in Dark mode for Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-11

After upgrading to Windows 11, the file explorer address bar remains white when in Dark mode.
[image]

Comment: Have you recently changed your theme?

Comment: I'm using the Windows default dark theme and not a custom theme,

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. If you have any references to AeroLite.msstyles, your theme will break. I did the following to fix my issue:

Step 1.
Open Run and type: `regedit`

Step 2.
Navigate to:  `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ThemeManager`

Step 3.
Replace DLLName with `%SystemRoot%\resources\themes\Aero\Aero.msstyles`

This works for Windows 10 and Windows 11.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't fix the problem on my system. `Dllname` is already set to "%SystemRoot%\resources\themes\Aero\Aero.msstyles", yet out of a sudden the menu bar is shown in white colour using the default dark theme.